# Error en la salida al extraer un int de un array bidimensional en C

Tags: array, c

Buenas tengo el siguiente código que me realiza el cálculo de un número combinacional:

```
int combinacional(int_pair par) {
int i,j;
int tabla[par.a+1][par.b+1] ;

if(par.b == 0 || par.b == par.a) {
   return 1;
}
else if (par.b == 1 || par.b == (par.a - 1)) {
    return par.a;
}
else {
   for (i=0; i<=par.a; i++) {
     tabla[i][0] = 1;
   }

   for (i=1; i<=par.a; i++) {
     tabla[i][1] = i;
   }

   for (i=2; i<=par.b; i++) {
     tabla[i][i] = 1;
   }

   for (i=3; i<=par.a;i++) {
     for (j=2; j<par.a; j++) {
       if(j<=par.b) {
         tabla[i][j] = tabla[i-1][j-1] + tabla[i-1][j];
       }
     }
   }
   }

   return tabla[par.a][par.b];
}
```

En ella hago uso de "int_pair" que sería un equivalente a una tupla en el cuál se puede seleccionar el primer valor o el segundo, también creo un array bidimensional para poder guardar los valores del triángulo se Pascal y coger al final el resultado de este. El error viene al mostrar la salida, para ello uso lo siguiente:

```
void test() {
list enteros = leerFichero4("ficheros/entradaE4.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < enteros.size; i++) {
    int_pair tupla = *(int_pair*) list_get(&enteros, i);
    int result = combinacional(tupla);
    printf("Entrada = %s; ", int_pair_tostring(&tupla, mem));
    printf("Salida = %i\n", result);
    printf("========================================\n");
}
}

int main() {
   test();
}
```

Esto me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Entrada = (10,1); Salida = 10
========================================
Entrada = (9,2); Salida = 36
========================================
Entrada = (8,3); Salida = 7105
========================================
Entrada = (7,4); Salida = -996404052
========================================
Entrada = (6,5); Salida = 6
========================================
```

La dos primeras salidas y la última son correctas. Sin embargo, las demás deben ser 56 y 35 y aparecen punteros a posiciones de memoria imagino.
Supongo que será algún error de punteros pero no logro encontrarlo.

Comment: Tu código carece del contexto que necesitamos para empezar a intentar averiguar dónde está tu error. ¿Cuál es la definición de `list`? ¿Cuál es la definición de `list_get`? ¿Cuál es la definición de `int_pair_tostring`? ¿Qué es un número combinacional y qué relación tiene con el triángulo de Pascal? ¿Qué compilador estás usando, soporta Arreglos de Tamaño Variable?

Comment: Uso MinGW, los arreglos que soporta son los mismos que soporta la última versión de C disponible  y esas definiciones son para crear un tipo "lista", obtener el valor y el tosring es para mostrar por pantalla la "tupla" como string de forma que C lo reconozca. Aún así, dudo que el error provenga de eso. Combinacional es una función que busca obtener el numero combinatorio de n sobre k. Lo intento hacer mediante programación dinámica y por eso uso el Triángulo de Pascal

Comment: Responder eso y responder nada es equivalente. Tu error puede estar en la definición de `list`, `list_get` o `int_pair_tostring`, pero no hay manera de saberlo porque no vemos dichas definiciones. Si usas la última versión de C disponible, tu código no soporta Arreglos de Tamaño Variable y en consecuencia tienes un error o alarma en `int tabla[par.a+1][par.b+1];` porque los arreglos se definen con constantes, no con variables.

Comment: Pues tiene que ser lo último. Ya que si cambio todo lo anterior y le paso directamente dos int n, k sin usar nada de int_pairs, list, etc... retorna lo mismo.

Comment: Ni siquiera entiendo el cambio que dices haber aplicado O_O

Comment: Muchas gracias, he cambiado la creación a una variable fija de 51 y ya funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues edito la respuesta para hacerla más clara, por si alguien entra en ella buscando información. Como bien me respondió en los comentarios @PaperBirdMaster. El error se encontraba en que la versión usada no permitía la creación de arrays donde las dimensiones variaran. Por tanto el array `tabla` era el causante del problema, pues se construía dependiendo de los valores recibidos por parámetro. Por tanto, la solución fue construirlo con tamaño [100][100], siendo de esta forma de un tamaño fijo.

Comment: Un ejemplo y tal vez una explicación mas completa del por que de tu respuesta ayudaría, checa [answer], ya que al momento tu aporte luce un tanto de baja calidad

Comment: Simplemente tenía la intención de cerrar la pregunta. Gracias a los comentarios de PaperBirdMaster pude arreglarlo creando el array "tabla" con un tamaño 100x100 en vez de con tamaño dinámico que cambiaba dependiendo de los parámetros pasados a la función.

Comment: Es excelente, sin embargo considera que esta publicación eventualmente será consultada por otras personas a las cuales les vendría bien una explicación del por que de esta solución

Comment: @Aprendiz he modificado la pregunta, gracias por el comentario.